# How to set a textbox value in a view using a return content of a controller method

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm totally new to `ASP.NET` and `MVC` architecture. I have a controller function and it is something like this.

```
public ActionResult Calculate()
{

    var Message = "Hello There!";
    return Content(Message);

}
```

I need to set this return value to a text box in a view..

if the name of the textbox is "text3", how can I do that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably want to return a `ViewResult` with a view model. Have a look into that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create a ViewModel to hold the message.

```
public class CalculateViewModel {
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Create a cshtml file to serve as View for this ViewModel. By convention, this file should be named like the action that renders it, i.e. `Calculate.cshtml`, and be placed in a folder with the name of the controller under `Views\`.

```
@model CalculateViewModel 

@* render textbox for "Message" property in ViewModel *@
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Message)
```

Note that this will render an `<input name="Message" />`. If you want the textbox to be named "text3", the property in the ViewModel should be named "text3" instead of "Message".

In the controller action, return a View with the correctly initialized ViewModel:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Calculate() {
    var vm = new CalculateViewModel {
        Message = "Hello There!";
    };
    return View("Calculate", vm);
}
```